# Incorrect output from the feature vector

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, feature-extraction

I have created a classifier for sentiment analysis and did not face any problem while training it. But while testing it, I am unable to get a correct output. The main problem here is that the feature vector that I am feeding to my classifier is not returning correct values.

Here's my implementation of the feature vector:

```
#Fucntion for feature vector for a single tweet
def getSVMFeatureVector(tweets):
        sortedFeatures = sorted(featureList)
        map = {}
        feature_vector = []
        for t in tweets:
            label = 0
            map = {}
            #Initialize empty map
            for w in sortedFeatures:
                map[w] = 0
            #Fill the map
            for word in t:
                if word in map:
                    map[word] = 1
            #end for loop
            values = map.values()
            feature_vector.append(values)                    
        return feature_vector
#end
```

While the correct vector return should have '1' placed at the places where there is a hit i.e the value matches to that of a value present in my feature list. But instead, it returns a vector full of 0s. I think there is a logical fault in this code of mine.

featureList contains feature words extracted from the data set.
Example: Suppose my dataset contains of all tweets from a football match. So feature list would look like this: featureList = ['football', 'el classico', 'messi', 'ronaldo', 'barcelona', 'madrid' ...]. These were prepared after pre-processing of the tweets scraped.

Comment: What is `featureList`? What the point of the `map` variable outside the `for` loop? What is the point of having twp nested `for` loops with the same `word` variable?

Comment: For featureList, I have included an example. I have used map for mapping the values inside of my feature_vector.  One for loop is for initialising it to 0. Another one is for checking if word exists or not.

Comment: Are you sure that your tweets are loaded properly (and that each tweet is indeed a list of words)? Maybe the issue is with the input data and the way your process it, not the algorithm itself.